# Does ReactDOM.render wait for the document to be loaded before rendering?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, document, react-dom

I'm wondering if I need to wait for the document to be loaded (i.e. listen to `DOMCOntentLoaded`) before calling `ReactDOM.render(...)`.  It doesn't seem like other React example apps are doing so, so I'm guessing inside the implementation of `ReactDOM.render` they already wait?

Comment: Could you post an example app which doesn't wait? I usually listen for the `DOMContentLoaded` event and would be interested to see the alternatives.

Comment: I believe since you explicitly pass an element to attach react apps to, there's no need to wait for anything. either the element you pass exists or it doesnt when calling `render`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You just need to ensure that the DOM element that your react code renders into is available at the time the `<script>` is evaluated. You can do this by placing the script after the dom element in your index.html file.

```
<!-- this will work -->
<div id="react-app"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./my-react-script.js"></script>

<!-- this will NOT work -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="./my-react-script.js"></script>
<div id="react-app"></div>
```